# Received Array From one Input Field How Can Validate it?

Tags: php

I want to get ten emails from user.how to check the user provide the correct email or not ? i am try multiple methods but failed to check it please help.

```
for($i=1;$i<=9;$i++)
{
    echo "<input type='text'  value='' name='email[]' class='form-control'>"."</br>";
}

// Php Code
// Step One Catch The Values
$email = $_POST['email'];
// Unset the empty values from array
foreach($email =>$key as $emails){
if($emails == ""){
 unset($email[$key]);
}
}
```

Here I am successfully done But when i try to validate it it return me errors which i was never face.
I want to remove html special character from input field and also validate my input using filter_var for email validation. I am trying to do it with loop through method but does not work.

Comment: could you please provide the error you receive?

Comment: Use `array_map()` function to do it on complete array

Answer (score 0):

To achieve that look over below code. As you are receiving the array of email as an input from the end user.

```
if(count($_POST['email']) > 0)
{
 $pattern = "/^\[?[0-9\.]+\]?$/";
  foreach($_POST['email'] as $email)
  {
   if (preg_match($pattern, $email) === 1) {
        // emailaddress is valid
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are writing foreach wrong way. try below code

```
foreach($email as $key=>$emails)
{
   if($emails == "")
   unset($email[$key]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and safest way to check whether an email address is well-formed is to use the [filter_var()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) function:

```
    if(count($_POST['email']) > 0)
    {
     $email = $_POST['email'];
     foreach($email as $key => $emails)
      {
       if(!filter_var($emails, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
       {
          //invalid email
           unset($email[$key]);
       }
       else
       {
          //valid email
       }
     }
  }
```

Comment: Its Can't Remove The invalid value from array :(